# Javascript - Firefox behavior blur by mouse click. Bug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, blur, onblur

**Scenario:** display alert message onblur (or onchange) as a part of javascript field validation.

**User action with onblur:**
1) click inside input
2) click outside the input
3) close the alert message
4) move mouse around

**Result:** *mousedown* seems to be performed at the position where you clicked out before the alert came up -- elements on the page get selected when you move the mouse around.
Note: This doesn't happen when tabbing out of the input.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/s9sc4/

```
<body>
Click inside the input and then outside of it.
<input type="text" onblur="alert('Close this alert message and move the mouse around.');" />
TEST TEST TEST
</body>
```

**Reproduced on:**
Firefox 28 and 29
Platforms: Windows 7 & 8 and OSX Mavericks (4 different machines).
Using a clean Firefox profile made no difference.

**QUESTION:**
Is this a bug, or default behavior? Chrome, Safari and IE don't behave like this.
If it's as designed, do I need to do something with preventDefault or cancel bubbling/stop propagation after the alert to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add:

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

This will solve your issue.

To answer your question: this seems to be [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=297134) of FireFox and needs a workaround. What happens is FireFox messed up the priority of events where `focus` is set first, prior to `onblur`. Browsers who don't have the bug will not fire the focus event when onblur occurs.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/hVf4f/)**

Comment: Thank you -- that should work for my applications. I wonder why Mozilla doesn't give higher priority to fixing basic things like this.

Comment: I don't really see the link to the bug you linked to, but I submitted this as a new bug, which has been confirmed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005606
It's backlogged unfortunately...

Comment: It's a bit indirect since the bug talks about `focus` issues. Although it's the root cause for this particular issue (imho). After searching some more I found [similar issues](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53579) dating way back to 2000 and they all require the same workarounds. It's a good thing they acknowledge it I guess.

Comment: Gosh, 14 years. That bug will probably never be fixed then, unless that particular part of Firefox ever gets an overhaul perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

That's interesting. This feels like a bug. I did get around it be calling `setTimeout`, and then calling `alert`:

```
<input ... onblur="setTimeout(function() { alert(...); }, 0);">
```